# How does the trait entity extraction in wit.ai work?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, wit.ai

Wit.ai provides an entity of type "trait". Wit.ai defines trait entities as

> When the entity value is not inferred from a keyword or specific
>   phrase in the sentence. There is no obvious association between
>   certain words in the sentence and the value of the entity, but rather
>   you need the sentence as a whole to determine the value.
>   (https://wit.ai/docs/recipes#which-entity-should-i-use)

I'm curious to know how does this work? For example,

```
I want to know the status
Check the status
How is it going?
```

I want to extract the entity `entities["cmd":"status"]` from all of these statements. How do I go on about starting to implement this?